# rspec w/IronRuby missing be_* methods

Tags: ruby, rspec, ironruby

My IronRuby install of the rspec gem seems to be lacking the automated be_* method helpers. For instance, the following code generates an undefined method error:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rspec'

x = 7
x.should == 7 # works
x.nonzero?.should == 7 #works
x.should be_nonzero # undefined method `be_nonzero' for main:Object
```

I used igem to install the rspec gem. Here is the list of my installed gems:

```
bewildr (0.1.14)
builder (3.0.0)
cucumber (0.6.3)
diff-lcs (1.1.3)
iron-term-ansicolor (0.0.3)
json_pure (1.7.3)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rspec (2.11.0)
rspec-core (2.11.1)
rspec-expectations (2.11.1)
rspec-mocks (2.11.1)
term-ansicolor (1.0.7)
treetop (1.4.10)
```

Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RSpec matchers are generally only available in an `it` block, in order to avoid polluting the global namespace. Have you tried running your code on a different Ruby implementation? You'll get the same error.

Comment: Hmm. You're right - putting the code into a describe...if... block solves this problem. But if this is so, how can I introduce these matchers when I want them outside of an it block - like inside a cucumber When /^ etc $/ do block? Or am I wrong in thinking this functionality comes from rspec?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem but your post inspired me to do some research. I've found solution here:
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/RSpec-Expectations
In short in my "features\support\env.rb" I have added this:

```
require 'rspec/expectations'
World(RSpec::Matchers)
```